# Android application crashes before start

Tags: java, android

Displaying two random numbers and counting scores for odd and even turns. When one of it reaches to 100, the application stops.

This is my java file of application

```
public class Board_Play1 extends Activity {

int d=0,a=0,b=0,turn=2;
Random random = new Random();
EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);


    diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));  
    p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
    p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));

    while(a!=100 && b!=100)
    {
        if(turn%2==0)
        {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
                    EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));

                }
            }); 
        }
        else
        {

            d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
            diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
        }

    if(turn%2==0)
            a+=d;
        else
            b+=d;

    if(a>100)
        a-=d;
    if(b>100)
        b-=d;


        p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
        p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
        turn++;
    }
    a=0;b=0;

}


}
```

It doesn't open and give an error saying `Unfortunately your app has stopped`. Why is this happening? What can I change?

Answer (score 1):

Move all this inside `onCreate` after `setContentView`

```
EditText diceno;
EditText p1;
EditText p2 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);
diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current view hierarchy. You ned to set the content of the layout to the activity first and then initialize vies by using `findViewById`.

Also there is no need to re- initialize editText in button onClick. Get rid of the below in the same

```
EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Also move this

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

before the while loop. no need to initialize everytime